# css issue for alignment of divs

Tags: css, html

I am working on this philippedecor.com site and I am having a difficulty in figuring out this css issue.
 When I on mouse over on  "Main categories" that appears on the right side, it shows a drop down with links in it.
Two things happens, 
1) in IE(7) - the drop down hides behind another div 
2) in both ie and ff, it pushes other div below that to go down and on mouse out, it looks fine.

I am not sure which css property can fix this.

please help me out

Comment: Sure, just add some code to your post or post a working site link.

Comment: When I got to philippdecor.com, I get a 404

Comment: random guess: position: absolute and z-index: 10

Comment: What do you mean by "code"? I don't see any code...

Comment: please check the site as I couldnt combine the code and paste it here.

Answer (score 1):

Next time, please make your URL clickable: http://philippedecor.com/

In Firefox, I also see a tiny bit of the background showing through the menu, [as you can see](http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2401/4514758240_5737f2b967_o.png). Mousing over this thing triggers a mouseout event, closing the menu. In IE 7, I don't see the push-down effect, only the hiding of the menu under the Flash panel and everything below it.

To prevent the menu pushing down other elements on your page, you should use `position: absolute` on `#downmenu` and probably incorporate it into the div containing "Main Categories" to position it in the right place. Use an appropiate `z-index` will likely prevent the drop down menu from popping under another div in IE (untested, as I don't have a debugging tool for IE at the university where I'm typing this message now).

Furthermore, I think you shouldn't use two menus containing exactly the same content, that can be confusing to visitors of your site (actually, I didn't read your post well enough and moused over the left instance). Also, you shouldn't put text in images without providing alternate texts, screen readers and the like can't "see" it this way (preferably use a suitable [image replacement technique](http://css-tricks.com/css-image-replacement/)). And all those `&nbsp;`s in the `li`s are totally unnecessary and not according to rules for semantic HTML; just use `padding` on them or something. By the way, you should make the rounded cursors of 'Main categories' transparent (now two little white corners are shown). Just my $ 0.02...